# Preloading has_many association with a subset of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a system that allows users to auction and bid on items. I have these models

`Item` (id, description)

`User` (id, name)

`Bid` (id, item_id, user_id, price)

`Sale` (id, item_id, seller_id, buyer_id)

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids
end
```

```
class Bid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :seller, foreign_key: seller_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :buyer, foreign_key: :buyer_id, class_name: 'User
  belongs_to :item
  has_many :bids, through :item
end
```

I am trying to make a page that lists out all the recent sales, and for each sale, lists out the bidding history of the eventual buyer.

So for example:

```
class SalesController < ApplicationRecord
  def index
    @sales = Sale.all.includes(:item, :bids)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% @sales.each do |sale| %>
  <%= sale.item.description %>

  <p>previous bids</p>
   <% sale.bids.select { |bid| bid.user_id == sale.buyer_id }.each do |bid| %>
     <%= bid.price %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine, but I'm having to preload **all** of the bids in the controller. Is there a way to only include the required subset? I feel like It should be possible to add an association to `Sale` such as `has_many :buyer_previous_bids, -> (??), class_name: 'Bid'` that can be preloaded `Sale.includes(:buyer_previous_bids)`

Comment: How does sale.bids work? you don't seem to have any association connecting them

Comment: Good point. I've updated my question. I think `bids` should be a `has_many :through :item` association

Answer (score 1):

I think due the relations you have between your models, and without adding anything else you can get access to both bids and items, INNER JOIN*ing* bids with sales through their `user_id` and `buyer_id` respectively, and to `items` through their primary/foreign keys:

```
Sale.joins("
  INNER JOIN bids b ON b.user_id = sales.buyer_id
  INNER JOIN items i ON i.id = b.item_id
")
```